# How to use button click and pass values to delete values from a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    private List<int> modelid = new List<int>();
    private List<int> modelrefno = new List<int>();
    private List<string> modelname = new List<string>();

int touchescount0 = 0;
int touchescount1 = 0;
int touchescount2 = 0;
```

Three button methods are given below when I click each buttons a key value is passed to the another place and finally reaches the Listadd() method.

```
public void AddPath()

{

key = 0;

}

public void AddModel()

{

key = 1;

}
public void AddNewmodel()

{

key = 2;

}
```

The value reaches the below method and the following models are instantiated.Adding the model information to different lists ir modelid,modelrefno and modelname.

```
public GameObject Listadd(ModelInfo info)


{


    key = info.shapeType;

if (key == 0)
        {

            touchescount0 = touchescount0 + 1;


            shape = Instantiate(models[key], new Vector3(info.px, info.py, info.pz), Quaternion.Euler(info.qx, info.qy, info.qz));


            modelid.Add(0);
            modelrefno.Add(touchescount0);
            shape.name = "Path" + " " + touchescount0;
            modelname.Add(shape.name);
            Debug.Log("Model Details " + modelid[0] + "-" + modelrefno[0] + "-" + modelname[0]);



        }
        else if (key == 1)
        {

            touchescount1 = touchescount1 + 1;

            GameObject objs = Instantiate(models[key], new Vector3(info.px, info.py, info.pz), Quaternion.Euler(info.qx, info.qy, info.qz));
            shape = objs;


            modelid.Add(1);
            modelrefno.Add(touchescount1);

            shape.name = "SBlue" + " " + touchescount1;
            modelname.Add(shape.name);


        }



else if (key == 2)
            {

            touchescount2 = touchescount2 + 1;

            GameObject objs = Instantiate(models[key], new Vector3(info.px, info.py, info.pz), Quaternion.Euler(info.qx, info.qy, info.qz));
            shape = objs;


            modelid.Add(1);
            modelrefno.Add(touchescount2);

            shape.name = "SBlue" + " " + touchescount2;
            modelname.Add(shape.name);


        }


}

    }
```

Now when I delete using a delete button the below method is used.Here I want to keep deleting the last kept model information.If I hit delete twice the last kept two model information are deleted.When I add  a single model and delete, accordingly it will delete but if I add multiple models the key value will be the last added model.So when I try to delete the information will be still there.How to delete multiple kept information from the list.

```
 public void DeleteShapes()
    {
            if (key == 0 && touchescount0 > 0)
            {
                touchescount0 = touchescount0 - 1;
            }
            if (key == 1 && touchescount1 > 0)
            {
                touchescount1 = touchescount1 - 1;
                Debug.Log("While Deleting SMblue = " + touchescount1);
            }

            if (key == 2 && touchescount2 > 0)
            {
                touchescount2 = touchescount2 - 1;

            }
            if(modelid.Count>0)
            {
                modelid.RemoveAt(modelid.Count - 1);

            }

            if (modelrefno.Count > 0)
            {
                modelrefno.RemoveAt(modelrefno.Count - 1);
            }

            if (modelname.Count > 0)
            {

                modelname.RemoveAt(modelname.Count - 1);
            }
            //Debug.Log("Model Details " + modelid[0] + "-" + modelrefno[0] + "-" + modelname[0]);


        }
```

Comment: Maybe you should try using `Stack` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Morasiu Thanks..worked well... write as an answer

Comment: You have three lists that contain related data.  You should create a custom class containing those pieces of data and have ONE list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=netframework-4.7.2). It's simple.

If you want add something to the top just use:

```
myStack.Push(myobject);
```

And to remove something from top of the stack:

```
myStack.Pop();
```

It is also a lot of faster so... no downsides.